# Generate dates between range in Excel

Tags: excel

Is it possible to automatically (without user interaction) generate dates between two that specify range?

Let's say that we need to insert start and end date in two cells, and that Excel autofill all dates between range.

Comment: The user will need to open the workbook and enter the start and end dates.  Depending on how that occurs, you can do this either with formulas or with an event-triggered macro.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

Put your start date in B2 and your end date in C2.

In the column to the right, make d2  = B2.

Make d3

```
=IF(D2<$C$2,D2+1,"")
```

Copy paste to all cells below D3 as far down as you need to go.

This will check to see if the previous date in the column has reached the end date or not. If not, it will fill in the next date. If it has reached the end date, the cell will be blank.